# Lightning Component in List View

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I know I am asking something crazy but just wanted to know has anyone ever tried to call a lightning component into the standard list views of any object. That is suppose I have a list view as 'All Accounts' on Account. So is it possible to call a lightning component into it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E572QAC), or, stated differently, no, you can't currently do this. I believe this will probably be in a later release, though we don't know when that might be.